# where can I find mysql.data.dll for c#

Tags: c#, mysql

All I keep on finding are source files for compiling the project myself (which keeps on failing).

Any ideas please?

Thank You!

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

Comment: Not very user friendly, and very late here to my defense :)

Comment: Please be aware that this connector is dual-licensed. GPL and Commercial. You may need to obtain commercial license if your project is not GPLed.

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Here is where you can download the latest MySql .NET driver for ADO.NET.](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/)

Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

[Connector/Net is a fully-managed ADO.NET driver for MySQL.](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.2.html)

Comment: You're linking to an old version, 6.3.4 is the latest stable release.

Comment: no, I only get source file downloaded. No binaries from some reason

Comment: @vondip, that's because you're clicking the wrong link... Click on the "Download"-link in the bottom - not the top one.

Comment: bah, latest version in dropdown on page... saved wrong link.  Looks like ya got it anyways ;)